# Disable a Plugin in Cordova

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I need to disable a plugin in Cordova. I don't want to uninstall it, I just want to, for a particular build, compile a version without that plugin.

In Phonegap Build (Adobe on the cloud service) you just only needed to take the plugin out of config.xml (Or comment it).

But in Cordova I just don't know what to do ..

1. I commented it on config.xml (Does this file serve for any purpose here anymore?). Nothing.
2. Took it out from package.json. Nada.
3. Took it out from package-lock.json. Nope.
4. Took it out from android.json on "platforms\android" (Although I saw this file regenerates with every build)
5. Took it out from android.json and fetch.json on the Plugins Folder and also nothing.

Any help?

Also, does anyone knows where can I find a guide with an updated Cordova structure and which are the key configuration files and what is the purpose of them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After you commented the plugin out on config.xml, remove the platform file and cordova add platform again.

In my experience, the plugin files inside the platform folder is unchanged when you remove some line in config.xml and run -cordova build only, you need to remove and re-add the platform to apply the change in plugins. Hope this help you ;)

(btw when you took it out in package.json & package-lock.json, cordova won't download the plugin to your plugin folder, but the plugins folder inside each platform remain unchanged, fyi)

Answer (score 0):

The config.xml file serves the same purpose in cordova as it does in phone gap build. Config.xml file is the key configuration file, its what's compulsory in making of your app. Config.xml file defines your app,it's features,its plugins,its author's name,mail id, its icons, splash screens and all. So you can remove the line corresponding to that plugin from config.xml file and compile your app again in cordova.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. It continues to do a lot of things. But doesn't have control over the plugins. Erased the one I wanted out from the file and it continued to work the same way, indeed started taking other plugins just to see if something weird was going on with the app doing something for what didn't have the plugin, and started deleting other plugins from there, like the splashscreen, and everything continues to work the same way. Or at least it's that way with Cordova 9.0.0

Comment: If those plugins are still working then i may not be the right person to answer your question. Sorry!